# FMDB cascade on self referenced key

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, fmdb

i have created an SQLite db using this statement:

> "CREATE TABLE Projects (Id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
>   productsIds TEXT, title TEXT, parentId INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(parentId)
>   REFERENCES Projects(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION);"

as you can see, i every Project may have 0 or many subProject.

i want to delete all subProjects (and subProjects of subProjects, and so on) if i delete the parent, but i delete a parent subProjects are not deleted.

insert row:

> INSERT INTO Projects (id,productsIds,title,parentId) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

delete row:

> DELETE FROM Projects WHERE id = 2

Im using FMDB.

could you please help on this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue may be that FOREIGN KEY support hasn't been enabled. To do so you may need to issue/run

```
pragma foreign_keys = ON;
```

As per :-

> #### 2. Enabling Foreign Key Support
>
> In order to use foreign key constraints in SQLite, the library must be
>   compiled with neither SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER
>   defined. If SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER is defined but SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY
>   is not, then SQLite behaves as it did prior to version 3.6.19
>   (2009-10-14) - foreign key definitions are parsed and may be queried
>   using PRAGMA foreign_key_list, but foreign key constraints are not
>   enforced. The PRAGMA foreign_keys command is a no-op in this
>   configuration. If OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY is defined, then foreign key
>   definitions cannot even be parsed (attempting to specify a foreign key
>   definition is a syntax error).
>
> Assuming the library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled,
>   it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the
>   PRAGMA foreign_keys command. For example:
>
> ```
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
> ```
>
> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards
>   compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database
>   connection. (Note, however, that future releases of SQLite might
>   change so that foreign key constraints enabled by default. Careful
>   developers will not make any assumptions about whether or not foreign
>   keys are enabled by default but will instead enable or disable them as
>   necessary.) The application can also use a PRAGMA foreign_keys
>   statement to determine if foreign keys are currently enabled. The
>   following command-line session demonstrates this:
>
> ```
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
> 0
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
> 1
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
> 0
> ```
>
> Tip: If the command "PRAGMA foreign_keys" returns no data instead of a
>   single row containing "0" or "1", then the version of SQLite you are
>   using does not support foreign keys (either because it is older than
>   3.6.19 or because it was compiled with SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER defined).
>
> It is not possible to enable or disable foreign key constraints in the
>   middle of a multi-statement transaction (when SQLite is not in
>   autocommit mode). Attempting to do so does not return an error; it
>   simply has no effect.

[SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)